# Class and Protocol Existential not work with custom protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I defined a custom protocol and used `Class and Protocol Existential`, which is new in Swift 4. It get error at run time. Here is my code:

```
protocol CustomProtocol: UIScrollViewDelegate {}

var test: UIViewController & CustomProtocol = UITableViewController() as! UIViewController & CustomProtocol
```

I tried empty protocol.
[image]

And protocol confirms to another.
[image]
Please help me with this, thanks!

Comment: Is your protocol declaration outside the class?

Comment: @ImadAli This is Playground. I tried in a Swift Project, I declared protocol inside class, and crashed still.

Comment: Even if it is a playground, Please declare your protocol outside class declaration.

Comment: @ImadAli I'm sorry I declared protocol outside in my swift project. And I tried outside in Playground, still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is **Protocol Composition** in **Swift4**.

In your code:

```
protocol CustomProtocol: UIScrollViewDelegate {}

var test: UIViewController & CustomProtocol = UITableViewController() as! UIViewController & CustomProtocol
```

`test` will accept anything that is **of type `UIViewController` and conforms to `CustomProtocol`**.

You are assigning an object of `UITableViewController` to it. But `UITableViewController` does not conform to `CustomProtocol` and hence causing the issue.

**Example:**

```
protocol CustomProtocol: UIScrollViewDelegate
{

}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomProtocol
{

}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var test: UIViewController & CustomProtocol = TableViewController() //HERE..
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I should extend UIViewController to confirm to CustomProtocol. I'm so so so sorry I forgot it's Swift not OC.

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example. Have a look.